# ES7 decorator on constructor

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I'm experimenting with ES7 decorators because I want to build a simple IOC utility based on Inject annotation to inject dependencies through constructor injection.

I have following test class:

```
import { Inject } from "./decorators/index";

export default class Container {

    #prop = null;


    @Inject
    constructor(prop) {
        this.#prop = prop;
    }

    getProp(prop) {
        return this.#prop;
    }

    meow() {

    }

}
```

Decorator function:

```
export const Inject = (target, key, descriptor) => {
    console.log('target', target);
};
```

This displays following error:

> Decorators can't be used with a constructor. Did you mean '@dec class
> { ... }'? (8:1) 6 | 7 | > 8 | @Inject | ^ 9 | constructor(prop)

The annotation works with regular methods.
Although I can use field / setter injection, I would prefer constructor injection much.

Is there a way around this?

I use babel-loader with plugin '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators' (legacy).

Comment: ES7 doesn't have decorators.

Comment: Try putting the decorator on the whole `class`. As the error message says, `constructor` cannot be decorated.

Comment: @Bergi Ok will try this.